# Feature transformation

Tags: functions, transformation

Does someone know a computationally efficient bijective function $f$ : $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (y_{0},y_{1})$ ?

Preferably, $(y_{0},y_{1})=(-1,1)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: There are so many of them. e.g. $k+\dfrac{2k}{\pi} atan(x)$ where $k=\dfrac{y_0+y_1}{2}$

Comment: I thought about shifting the tangens function as as well! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many examples:

The first example is that $f(x)$ is a monotonous function who with limits on infinity converge to the end point.

For instance, $f(x) = a\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2k}+1}}+b$ where $k$ is a natural number and $a+b =y_{1}$ and $a-b = y_{0}$.

since $g(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2k}+1}}$ is a [injective  function over R](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872414/proof-that-a-function-is-injection/1872419#1872419). It is easy to show that $f(x):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (y_{0},y_{1})$ is bijective function.

Or $f(x)$ can be $a \tanh(x) + b$, where a and b satisfies same condition stated above.

The second example is:

$f^{-1}(x) $ can be any monotonous function which send all members in $(y_{0},y_{1})$ to $R$, such as $\tan {x}$(as in comment) or [$\frac{A}{x-y_0} + \frac{B}{x-y_1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872541/if-a-and-b-are-positive-constants-show-that-fracax-1-fracbx-2/1872553#1872553).

Comment: You are welcome. I just share my own experience.